# SSRS Divide a sum of a group on a sum of another group SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hello I have this table

it have a 2 groups

1-Housing unit type as parent

2-Locality type as a child for housing unit and as a parent for Total

% for each urban or Rural for housing unit type is the No./Total housing unit type No.

```
=iif(reportitems("TotalNo").value=0,"",
Sum(Fields!No.Value)/reportitems("TotalNo").value*100)
```

the problem in this code that it always divide urban or rural on Urban value only.. it doesn't divide Rural on Rural  as you can see in the figure below

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I believe that the code snippet you provide in your question is syntactically incorrect.  ReportItems should be followed by an exclamation point, and I'm not sure that the parentheses and quotes are valid either.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the Design view but I think the issue is that you are using Report Items and it's picking the first one it finds instead of choosing the correct one. You probably have one cell that gets split between the Rural and Urban.

This is the best way I can think of off to do this is to use the dataset total for each locality:

```
=Sum(Fields!No.Value) / 
 IIF(Fields!Locality.Value = "Rural", 
  Sum(IIF(Fields!Locality.Value = "Rural", Fields!No.Value, 0), "DataSet1"), 
  Sum(IIF(Fields!Locality.Value = "Urban", Fields!No.Value, 0), "DataSet1") )
```